# Can integrals with respect to time-changed Brownian motion be seen as integrals with respect to Brownian motion?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $X_t:=W_{t\wedge \tau}$ for $t\ge 0$, where $(W_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is a standard Brownian motion and $\tau:=\inf\{t\ge 0: |W_t|=1\}$. It holds

$$X_t=\int_0^t {\bf 1}_{\{|X_s|<1\}}dW_s,\quad \forall t\ge 0.$$

Set $f(t):=t/(1-t)$ and $Z_t:=X_{f(t)}$ for $t\in [0,1)$. Is it true that

$$Z_t =\int_0^t {\bf 1}_{\{|Z_{s}|<1\}}dW_{f(s)},\quad \forall t\in [0,1)?$$

If so, does there exist some Brownian motion, denoted by $B$, s.t.

$$Z_t =\int_0^t a(s,Z_s)dB_{s},\quad \forall t\in [0,1)$$

holds for some measurable function $a$?

Comment: Indeed,  $Z_t = \int_0^t  {\bf 1}_{\{|Z_{s}|<1\}} dW_{f(s)}$ for $t \in [0,1)$ by the time change formula for Itô integrals.  Moreover, $Z_t =\int_0^t a(s,Z_s)dB_{s}$ where $B_t = \int_0^{f(t)} (1-s) d W_s$ is an $\mathcal{F}_{f(t)}$-Brownian motion and $a(s,Z_s) = {\bf 1}_{\{|Z_{s}|<1\}} (1-s)^{-1}$, which also follows from the time change formula for Itô integrals and the chain rule for inverse functions $(f^{-1})'(t) = 1/f'(f^{-1}(t))$.  For more detail see, e.g., Theorem 8.5.7 of B. Øksendal "Stochastic Differential Equations : An Introduction with Applications".

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Many thanks for the answer. I appreciate it